# How can I iterate (if possibile) in Thymeleaf over a list returned by a javaScript function?

Tags: javascript, loops, thymeleaf

My Thymeleaf code:

```
<div class="funzionalitaDecor" th:each="azienda : ${prova()}">
  <div th:text="${azienda.}" th:value="${azienda}" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>
</div>
```

My Java Script code:

```
function prova(){
  const lista = ["prova1", "prova2", "prova3"];
  return lista;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. Thymeleaf runs on the server, JavaScript runs in the browser at the client.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do, and why you need a JavaScript array to do it? Maybe there is an alternative approach we can suggest. (If you simply have a list of hard-coded strings, then you can use a Java `List<String>`.)